# Ramanujan graphs in Polynomial time

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, algorithms, bipartite-graphs

I am a research scholar with a computer science background, currently working on graph theory. I am working on a reduction to prove that a problem is NP-complete. I need to include the Ramanujan graph in a gadget that I am working on. As this is a polynomial time reduction, the construction has to be done in polynomial time. Hence, looking for a possibility of constructing Ramanujan graphs in polynomial time. 
 From the history of Ramanujan graphs, there are various methods to construct Ramanujan graphs for all degrees and sizes, some of which are given below. It was proved that the bipartite Ramanujan graphs can be constructed in polynomial time, but is there an approach to construct the Ramanujan graphs also in polynomial time? The papers cited below are completely theoretical, I am finding it difficult to analyse the time complexity of the approaches given in the papers, could someone please clarify this?

Various approaches to construct Ramanujan graphs:

1. Lubotzky, A.; Phillips, R.; Sarnak, P., Ramanujan graphs, Combinatorica 8, No. 3, 261-277 (1988). ZBL0661.05035.
2. Margulis, G. A., Explicit group-theoretical constructions of combinatorial schemes and their application to the design of expanders and concentrators, Probl. Inf. Transm. 24, No. 1, 39-46 (1988); translation from Probl. Peredachi Inf. 24, No. 1, 51-60 (1988). ZBL0708.05030.
3. Morgenstern, Moshe, Existence and explicit constructions of (q+1) regular Ramanujan graphs for every prime power (q), J. Comb. Theory, Ser. B 62, No. 1, 44-62 (1994). ZBL0814.68098.
4. Pizer, Arnold K., Ramanujan graphs and Hecke operators, Bull. Am. Math. Soc., New Ser. 23, No. 1, 127-137 (1990). ZBL0752.05035.
5. Marcus, Adam W.; Spielman, Daniel A.; Srivastava, Nikhil, Interlacing families. I: Bipartite Ramanujan graphs of all degrees, Ann. Math. (2) 182, No. 1, 307-325 (2015). ZBL1316.05066.

Comment: Simultaneously cross-posted to https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/52877/construction-of-ramanujan-graphs-in-polynomial-time

Comment: Do you really need specifically Ramanujan graphs, or do you just need polynomial-time constructible expanders?

Comment: I am looking for Ramanujan graphs, as they have some lower bound on their girth.

Comment: If the bound on girth also holds for bipartite ramanujan graphs, that also works as the bipartite ramanujan graphs are constructible in polynomial time.

Comment: To extend the comment by  Emil Jeřábek, it is usually considered to be bad form to cross-post: to post the same question on multiple sites at the same time, simply to avoid duplication of effort in responses.  Best to leave a few days (better a week) between posts.

Comment: Yes, the LPS Ramanujan graphs are constructible in polynomial time, for example. In the literature, "explicit" means "polynomial-time constructible"; see section 2 of the survey of Hoory, Linial, and Wigderson for more details. Also, it's not known if families of Ramanujan graphs exist of all degrees -- that's a major open problem.

Comment: So to sum it up, 6-regular Ramanujan graphs of any arbitrary size can be constructed in polynomial time. But, for 7-regular graphs it is unknown. Am I right? @Kevin

Comment: @BalchandarReddy That's right.